# How do I get web component slots to work?

Tags: html, web-component, shadow-dom, custom-element

I've copied MDN's example (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Web_Components/Using_templates_and_slots) but don't get it to work
here are my components:

```
<link rel="import" href="../molecules/main-menu__topbar.html">


<template id="main-menu">
  <p>I'M THE MENU ELEMENT</span>
  <main-menu__topbar></main-menu__topbar>
  <main-menu__topbar>
    <span slot="my-text">Let's have some different text!</span>
  </main-menu__topbar>

</template>

<script>
  (function() {
    var importDoc = document.currentScript.ownerDocument;

    var proto = Object.create(HTMLElement.prototype);

    proto.createdCallback = function() {

      var template = importDoc.querySelector('#main-menu');

      var clone = document.importNode(template.content, true);

      var root = this.createShadowRoot();
      root.appendChild(clone);
    };

    document.registerElement('main-menu', {prototype: proto});
  })();
</script>
```

and the imported topbar:

```
<template id="main-menu__topbar">
  <div class="main-menu__topbar">
    <p>I'm the topbar</p>
    <p><slot name="my-text">My default text</slot></p>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  (function() {
    var importDoc = document.currentScript.ownerDocument;

    var proto = Object.create(HTMLElement.prototype);

    proto.createdCallback = function() {

      var template = importDoc.querySelector('#main-menu__topbar');

      var clone = document.importNode(template.content, true);

      var root = this.createShadowRoot();
      root.appendChild(clone);
    };

    document.registerElement('main-menu__topbar', {prototype: proto});
  })();
</script>
```

How do I get the second top bar within the menu to display "Let's have some different text!"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`createShadowRoot()` is related to Shadow DOM v0 and it won't work with `<slot>` elements but only with `<content>` elements.

`<slot>` is related to Shadow DOM v1 and it won't work with `createShadowRoot()` but only with `attachShadow()`.

Because Shadow DOM v0 is deprecated I recommend to use v1 and therefore to replace `createShadowRoot`:

```
 var root = this.attachShadow( { mode: 'open' } )
```

*Note*: you should also use Custom Elements v1 instead of v0